# How to filter objects for users in queue

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a todo app and there is a feature of queue accomplishment. Say User 1, User 2 and User 3 are workers and do their task but sequentially in queue. What do I mean under `sequentially in queue` is until User 1 won't mark task as done this task won't appear for User 2 and 3. After User 1 checks task as accomplished, the task will be visible for User 2 but not for User 3 because User 2 is making this task and it should be fully done. After User 2 checks task as done it will be User 3's turn to do.
My model looks like this:

```py
class Todo(model.Models):
   # some other fields...
   workers = models.ManyToMany(User, related_name='todos')
   # after user checks a todo task he is counted as worker that fulfilled his duties
   # todo won't be shown to fulfilled users
   fulfilled_workers = models.ManyToMany(user, blank=True)
```

How to filter Todo table to show tasks for user who is first in M2M relationship but not for those who go after him?

Comment: How are you providing the order in your m2m relationship, i.e. how to you guarantee that User 1 is really first in line?

Comment: Actually this is not so necessary, because User model has some bool fields that we filter before adding them into workers M2M field and then we use custom order with annotation. I hid such details to not to overload people. Don't worry users are saved in that order that I want.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot preserve a specific order in an m2m field without some kind of ordering. Anyway, I would say that [SubQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) is the approach, annotating the qs with the first user in line and then filtering by that user